# How do I convert a stream of images to a path? (xamarin-forms)

Tags: xamarin.forms

I used the Xamarin(Photo Picker) example and was able to output the image using this code
`image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);`

How do I convert a stream of images to a `file.Path`?

I want to save the path to the image to a local database.

Comment: Xamarin Essentials includes a MediaPicker that will return a file path for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,it is recommended that you use [Xamarin.Essentials: Media Picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/media-picker?tabs=android) to achieve this.

You can get the  `FullPath` of your image except the stream.

Please refer the following code:

```
    async void Button_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var result = await MediaPicker.PickPhotoAsync(new MediaPickerOptions
        {
            Title = "Please pick a photo"
        });

        if (result != null)
        {
            var stream = await result.OpenReadAsync();

            resultImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);

            // you can get the FullPath of current photo
            string path = result.FullPath;
        }
    }
```

Comment: After selecting the image or deselecting the image by the user. The onResume method is executed. Question: How can I track the user's return in the onResume method? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an Image in your UI, it can have different types of Sources. It can be from a File, a URL or a Stream.

A stream is in memory only, so if you want a path to a file, you will have to convert it to a file first.

```
using (System.IO.FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(filePath))
{
stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
}
```

And then you can get the path to your file.

You can save the file wherever you want, I recommend using [Xamarin.Essentials FileSystem Helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/file-system-helpers?tabs=android)